# Check if Object value equals to string value

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6

Well i have a scenario in ES6 , i am using vuejs for current module .

I need to check if a string value exists in an array object .

```
let obj1 = [{name: "abc ced", id: 1},
           {name: "holla' name", id: 2},
           {name: "3' name", id: 3}]
let obj2 = { key: "3' name" , key1: 2 }
```

I need to get object for obj1 where name property value of obj2 exists in obj1 . doing it like

```
 _.each(obj1, function(obj){
     for (var k in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
            if (obj[k] === obj2.key) {
                  console.log(obj)
            }
         }
   })
```

am i missing something ? as console never logs any value .

Note :

I am using loadash , and tried to use find too

```
 let result = _.find(obj1 , {name: obj2.key})
 console.log(result)
```

it will work , if will try to use

```
let result = _.find(obj1 , {id: obj2.key1})
console.log(result)
```

So for integer match it works fine , but for strings no console .

but looks nothing . then i tried other solutions as given above

**Note: everything was working fine , only thing i was missing was i was not checking string case , as there were some uppercase and capitalise problem . so covert comparable string to lower and upper case , so you don't at-least make these silly mistakes**

cheers

Comment: you are checking `obj1.key`. should be `obj2.key`

Comment: can you please clear one thing, do you want to check some specific key from obj1 like `name` or do you just want to find the match with any key present in the obj1?

Comment: @RaghavGarg well i want to check if in obj1 , there is any object which have name equals to obj2.key  . So it is a specific key name in obj1

Comment: okay, thank for clearing that up. One more thing in your update you said that the lodash code is also not working, right?

Comment: Also, your code will check for any field(in obj1) equality match with `obj2.key`, so according to your update in comments, maybe you should consider the answers given.

Comment: @RaghavGarg loadash works fine , it's just about not getting result when i try to find if value exists them .Have updated Sample data . One more thing , when i try to match integer value it works fine , but for string it is not working

Comment: @AnilSharma could you please see my updated answer, and share if it solves your problem?

Comment: @RaghavGarg thanks for taking your time , Well it does not looks solving my problem , i have tried these solutions already , but it is not working for string case only , i know below in snippet it works fine , but in my environment it is not working . As i have mentioned in my question , it does work when i check for integer , but not for string .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153495/discussion-between-raghavgarg-and-anil-sharma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get first object that returns `true` on condition you can use `find()` otherwise you can use `filter()`.

```js
let obj1 = [{name: 'abc ced', id: 'ced'},
           {name: 'holla name', id: 'xyz'}]
let obj2 = { key: 'abc ced' }

var result = obj1.find(({name}) => obj2.key == name)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , tried but no luck , can you see my updated question , thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash `_.find`. Read more about [lodash find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find).

```js
let obj1 = [
    { name: "abc ced", id: "ced"},
    { name: "holla' name", id: "xyz"},
    { name: "3' name", id: "xz"},
    { name: 5, id: "yz"}
];
let obj2 = { key: "3' name" }
let obj3 = { key: 5 }

var result = _.find(obj1, { name: obj2.key });
console.log(result)

var result = _.find(obj1, { name: obj3.key });
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```